# vb.net removing items from listbox that are in another listbox

Tags: vb.net, linq, loops, foreach, listbox

I have two listboxes, one contains an approved list of items, which is used to loop through listbox1 items to see if the items in there contain any of the items from the approved items (for example '.txt')

If the item doesn't contain the approved item then it's removed.
The problem is when I add a second approved item, for example '.pdf', all of the '.txt' files are removed from the list as well because of the loop.

Any ideas would be appreciated to fix this, I want to keep all of the items that are approved in the listbox! Thanks

```
For Each item As Object In Me.lstApprovedItems.Items
For i As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
     If Not ListBox1.Items(i).Contains(item) Then
         ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i)
     End If
Next
```

Comment: I used this method in the end. Worked perfectly! http://stackoverflow.com/a/29656168/4764366

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes, if 'item' is ".pdf", then ListBox1.Items(i) doesn't contain 'item' if ListBox1.Items(i) is ".txt".  Instead of a slow inefficient nested For loop, try using some LINQ instead. How about something like this?

```
Dim list1 as list(of string) = (From Item in Listbox1.Items Select Item Where lstApprovedItems.items.Contains(Item)).tolist()
```

My syntax on the Contains part may be a bit off, but you can see where I'm going.

That will then give you a list of all the items currently in Listbox1.items which are also in lstApprovedItems.items.  You could then rebind your listbox1 to use that.

Comment: I get this error :

Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Object)' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)'.

but i see where you are going with it, thanks!

Comment: Ah, that makes sense actually.  "Item" is an object, not a string.  You'll want something like "Item.Content" I think.